# Сравнение больших массивов в PHP

Tags: php

Приветствую. Есть такая задача

Предположим, что имеется 2 многомерных массива

Один из них (пусть это будет **$array1**):

```
Array (
    [299292] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 299292
            [ID_EL] => 
            [ARTICUL] => 336867
            [TOVAR] => Шезлонг Garden Way LOUIS-A 76015 черный
            [MODEL] => LOUIS-A 76015 черный
            [ROD] => Спорт и отдых
            [CATEGORY] => Спорт и отдых
            [SUBCATEGORY] => Качели и гамаки
            [PRICE] => 7200
            [BRAND] => Garden Way
            [NAME] => Шезлонг
            [RRC] => РРЦ
        )

    [299291] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 299291
            [ID_EL] => 
            [ARTICUL] => 336866
            [TOVAR] => Шезлонг Garden Way LOUIS-A 76015 бежевый
            [MODEL] => LOUIS-A 76015 бежевый
            [ROD] => Спорт и отдых
            [CATEGORY] => Спорт и отдых
            [SUBCATEGORY] => Качели и гамаки
            [PRICE] => 7200
            [BRAND] => Garden Way
            [NAME] => Шезлонг
            [RRC] => РРЦ
        )

    [299290] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 299290
            [ID_EL] => 
            [ARTICUL] => 336865
            [TOVAR] => Шезлонг Garden Way BRIGO 770505 черный
            [MODEL] => BRIGO 770505 черный
            [ROD] => Спорт и отдых
            [CATEGORY] => Спорт и отдых
            [SUBCATEGORY] => Качели и гамаки
            [PRICE] => 5700
            [BRAND] => Garden Way
            [NAME] => Шезлонг
            [RRC] => РРЦ
        )  /*и тд*/ )
```

Второй массив - **$array2**:

```
Array
(
    [111113] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 1314124
            [NAME] => Шезлонг Garden Way LOUIS-A123 76015 черный
        )

    [111112] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 299291
            [NAME] => Шезлонг Garden Way LOUIS-A12 76015 бежевый
        )

    [11111] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 13253325
            [NAME] => Шезлонг Garden Way BRIGO 770505 черный
        )
/*и тд*/
)
```

Каждый массив содержит по 10000+ вложенных массивов.

Мне нужно сравнить первый массив по ключу TOVAR с массивом вторым по ключу NAME. Если наблюдается совпадение произвести некоторые несложные операции. Но суть не в этом. Вопрос вот в чем: как максимально быстро и качественно это сделать?

Ведь перебор типа (алгоритм сравнения) типа:

```
foreach($array1 as $row)
        foreach ($array2 as $cat)
            if ($row['TOVAR']==$cat['NAME'])
                echo 'Равны: '.$row['TOVAR'].' и '.$cat['NAME'].'<br/>';
            else
                echo 'Не равны: '.$row['TOVAR'].' и '.$cat['NAME'].'<br/>';
```

будет работать вхолостую на многих итерациях и это очень скажется на скорости. Как заюзать в моем случае array_intersect(); тоже не знаю, т.к. сравнение идёт по разным ключам (да и не нужен отдельный массив). Я думаю операции проводить сразу в цикле на лету (в случае совпадения, например, нужно копирнуть *ID* из второго массива вместо *ID* массива первого)

Что посоветуете? Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

После прочтения такого хочется с тигром побороться...

1. Откуда в PHP взялись 2 (*джва*, Карл!) массива по 10k+ элементов?
   Нельзя такими пачками затягивать данные в PHP! Надо по 20-50-100
   записей забирать (постранично), вы что нафик хотите убить сервер? у
   вас миллион пользователей придет, запустит эту ... и что - в каждой
   сессии будет торчать половина вашей базы? Что будет с сервером?
2. все эти ваши сравнения в PHP это мартышкин труд, надо просто
   грамотно написать SQL запрос (да-да, запрос на 5-10 строк), который
   то же самое сделает на уровне СУБД, которая для того и сделана,
   чтобы что-то выбирать, с чем-то сравнивать, и большими пачками в том
   числе.

Я бы SQL ввел обязательным начиная класса с 6-го средней школы, а то потом такого в PHP понаписывают!
Если, млин, не хотите / не можете / времени нету чтобы запрос написать - ну напишите вы сюда, объясните задачу - через день для вас напишут несколько вариантов... 
Ну нельзя же так издеваться над Вселенским Разумом!

Comment: Ерунду какую то пишите, вы понимаете что задача может придти откуда угодно, как и данные. Может там бабуся собирала эти 10к строк в какой-нибудь текстовик, это не важно. Важна логическая составляющая вопроса "как такое сделать быстрее чем перебором". Понятно что если вы начинаете изначально разбираться в вопросе, до того как у вас даже данные будут, вы сделаете более правильно. А если уже данные есть? Придется плясать от этого, и язык написания тут совершенно не причем (взято из комментов от другого ответа)

Comment: @Василий Барбашев, ерунды никакой не пишу, чего и Вам пожелаю ;-)

Comment: По самим массивам видно, что выбраны данные запросом из базы, и что данные характерные для магазина - нечего тут фантазировать про бабущек и "добрыми" советами про алгоритмы вводить начинающих разработчиков в еще большие заблуждения, чем те в которых они уже находятся. 
А потом людям приходится ходить в эти магазины, а хозяевам думать почему продажи не идут...

Comment: Я написал общий комментарий на тематику ответов к вопросам, а вы только на этот вопрос смотрите. Мыслите шире. И не надо дискутировать, мы в принципе оба правы.

Comment: На данный момент операцию нужно совершить, не имея доступа к БД, а имея лишь то, что имею (2 массива)

Comment: `Too toxic`. Кто вам сказал что тут вообще есть сервер, субд и тд. Разглагольствования на тему программы средней школы вообще за рамками. Мир не ограничен тем классом задач, которые решаете вы.

Answer (score 1):

Полностью согласен с предыдущим оратором, такое нужно делать на стороне БД.

Но если очень хочется [array_udiff](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-udiff.php) в помощь.

Немного поясню - колбек функия возвращает 0, если мы считаем, что элементы равны и не нулевое значение в противном случае.

Так мы должны получить элементы, которые присутствуют в обоих массивах:

```
function compare_func($a, $b) 
{
    if($a['TOVAR']==$b['NAME']) return 1; else return 0;
}

$in1andIn2 = array_udiff($array1, $array2, 'compare_func'));
```

Comment: В вопросе ни слова о бд. С чего вы взяли, что она там есть.

Comment: А откуда данные? Из воздуха? Ну, может быть, из файла и т.п. Тогда нужно загонять в бд и там с ними работать. Если это не разовая задача конечно. Для разовой задачи не стоит, согласен.

Comment: `return 1; else return 0;` - ненужные буквы.

Comment: в вопросе потому нет, что правильный вопрос - это половина ответа, вот и пытаемся намекнуть автору прямо и косвенно )

Comment: а если это разовая задача - тогда что угодно можно взять - Python, C++, Бейсик - но не PHP, согласитесь ))

Comment: @EugeneBartosh, вы серьёзно? Бейсик, но не PHP?

Comment: @vp_arth, вполне серьезно - а чем же вы думаете Visual Basic плох для этой задачи, если просто надо взять 2 массива из файлов и сравнить? )... я при этом конечно не хотел никого обидеть, что php мол плохой язык - просто мне лично это даже не пришло бы в голову :-))

Comment: Тогда уже эксель. Хотя есть подозрение, что данные имеено отуда.

Comment: Ок, `а чем же вы думаете PHP плох для этой задачи, если просто надо взять 2 массива из файлов и сравнить?`

Comment: я не думаю что php чем-то плох, хотя есть вестчи и получше, просто обычно ближе под рукой оказывается что-нибудь другое

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($array1 as $row)
    foreach ($array2 as $cat){}
```

Основная проблема этого алгоритма - квадратичная асимптотика.
Говоря по простому - количество итераций тут `N*M`

Чтобы превратить её в линейную, давайте создадим индекс:

```
$index = [];
foreach($array1 as $key => $row) {
  if (!isset($index[$row['TOVAR']])) $index[$row['TOVAR']] = [];
  $index[$row['TOVAR']][] = $key;
}
```

Теперь, когда у нас есть индекс, мы можем искать в нём:

```
foreach ($array2 as $cat){
  if (!empty($index[$cat['NAME']])) {
    echo 'Найдены совпадения:' . count($index[$cat['NAME']])."\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: а на построение индекса у нас какая ассимптотика? если пузырьком то примерно NxN, ну норм алгоритмом скажем NxNx0.4... итого получили (NxNx0.4+M) вместо NxM - много выиграли?

Comment: В приведённом коде асимптотика N+M, вставка элемента в массив(в php это что-то вроде HashMap) операция константная. О каком таком пузырьке речь?

Comment: об алгоритме сортировки методом пузырька

Comment: Я о том, куда вы его притулить собрались?

Comment: vp_arth, не я для "наглядности" про пузырёк вспомнил, намекнул что построение индекса небесплатно :-)

Comment: Кстати, `NxNx0.4 = N*N`, изменение константы не меняет асимптотику. Нормальным алгоритмом будет `N*log(N)`. Но непонятно, что тут сортировать.

Comment: построение индекса эквивалентно сортировке по ассимптотике

Comment: Вы код вообще видите? Вы вставку элемента в HashMap называете построением индекса?

Comment: а да, сорри, я на код не смотрел - просто прочитал "давайте создадим индекс"